# How can i store and execute a SQL file in a silverlight program?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I've found some information on how to store resources in SL program. But how can i store a file that contains SQL code, and run that code against a database?

I already have my SL program able to query the database, i need to know how i can store the SQL file as a resource AND execute the query from my SL program.

anyone have any leads on how to do this?

Comment: See if this helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikola/archive/2008/05/14/embedded-resources.aspx - save the sql file as a regular embedded resource. Access the query string with method above and use it to query the DB.

Comment: thanks for your help Blachsma, i was able to store and execute the sql file as i wanted.